# Querying Different Categories in Different Loop With Different Offsets

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach, offset

I have four loops. In the first loop I want to display all current articles from all categories (breaking news). In the 2nd loop only articles with the category 4,5,6,7 should be displayed. But if in the 1st loop an article from these categories were published, this newest article should not appear in the 2nd loop. So far I have only read about the general exclusion of articles but nothing about conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`category__not_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters):

```
$include_cats = array( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
$exclude_cats = array( 3 ); // 'breaking news' TERM ID

$posts_args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'post',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'        => 4 ,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
    'category__in'          => $include_cats,
    'category__not_in'      => $exclude_cats,
    'orderby'               => 'date',

);

$posts = new WP_Query( $posts_args );

if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $posts->post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( $posts->post->ID ); ?>">
            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail( $posts->post->ID ) ) {
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $posts->post->ID, $img, array( 'class' => 'post-thumb' ) ); // YOUR IMAGE SIZE
            } else {
                echo '<img class="' . $img . '" src="placeholder.png" width="150" height="150" alt="' . get_the_title( $posts->post->ID ) . '">'; //ADD PLACEHOLDER IMAGE HERE
            }
            ?>
            <h3 class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title( $posts->post->ID ); ?></h3>
            <span class="author"><?php echo get_the_author( $posts->post->ID ); ?></span>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also had your approach in mind at first. The only problem is, if I publish an article with a different category ID in the 1st loop (e.g. 24) then the posts do not slide into the second loop. They remain excluded. Do you know what I mean. I think I need to somehow compare the post IDs. I need to determine the post ID in the first loop and run a query with the second loop. If the post ID is equal, the item may not appear in the second loop, if it is not equal, it may appear in the second loop, as long as it is allowed to appear there after the category ID.

Comment: I have the solution:   

`<h2>Loop n°1</h2>
<?php
$ids = array();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_title();
?>
<?php $ids[]= $post->ID;
endwhile; ?>
 
<h2>Loop n°2</h2>
<?php
query_posts("showposts=50");
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)) {
  the_title();?>
<?php }
endwhile; ?>`

from here: [link] (https://www.isitwp.com/avoid-duplicate-posts-in-multiple-loops/)